# Kafdrop (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka

I setup Kafka and Zookeeper on my local machine and I would like to use [Kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop) as UI. I tried running with docker command below:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9000:9000 \
    -e KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=<localhost:9092> \
    -e JVM_OPTS="-Xms32M -Xmx64M" \
    -e SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH="/" \
    obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
```

and I get `-bash: https://locahost:9092: No such file or directory`

When I remove the *KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT* parameter, the application run but I got error below:

```
[AdminClient clientId=kafdrop-admin] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-07-22 09:39:29.108  WARN 1 [| kafdrop-admin] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient
```

I did setup Kafka Server's listener setting to this but did not help.

`listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

I found [this similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop/issues/35) but couldn't understand most of the answers.

Comment: Are you running Kafka & zookeeper in Docker or Standalone

Comment: No, they are both installed locally

Comment: Then you can build the code available github and run the jar.

Comment: Running JAR file works. I wanted to use the docker image though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka is not HTTP-based. You do not need a schema protocol to connect to Kafka, and angle brackets do not need used.

You also cannot use `localhost`, as that is Kafdrop container, not Kafka.

I suggest you use [Docker Compose with Kafdrop and Kafka](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop/blob/master/docker-compose/kafka-kafdrop/docker-compose.yaml)

Answer (score 2):

I followed what @OneCricketeer said in his answer and everything worked perfectly
Here what I did :

- I downloaded the compose file from GitHub the link above or [Click here](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop/blob/master/docker-compose/kafka-kafdrop/docker-compose.yaml)
- Run the compose file by going to the directory where the file exists and run it using cmd `docker-compose up`
- Stop all your kafka server and Zookeeper because everything going to be downloaded with the `docker-compose` command
- after go to http://localhost:9000/ and Voila
  [image: Kafdrop dashboard]

Comment: once you edit the yaml and run docker-compose up , since you have it on local machine , is there any issue of using 127.0.0.1 , the way you explained, means to create a proxy ...

Comment: I did not create any proxy just run the docker-compose and check if the images are up
if you have issues, please elaborate

Comment: actually it works fine for me as well, but always after sometime the site stop loading. Have you faced similar issue?